# WeMo Local SDK Demo iOS App DidFoundDevice Never Called

Tags: ios, sdk

I downloaded 2 third party apps capable of controlling my WEMO Link and they detected my 2 WeMo LED Bulbs straight away. However, when I downloaded the WeMo SDK Demo app, it never detects anything. the DidFoundDdevice delegate method is never called. I have no idea why..

I tried contacting weMo Developers and they replied once and never again.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow Below Process

1.import #import "WeMoDiscoveryManager.h"

2.Define a Delegate in .h file of your view controller and create object of WeMoDiscoveryManager

```
   @interface ViewController : UIViewController<WeMoDeviceDiscoveryDelegate>
    {
        WeMoDiscoveryManager*   discoveryManager;
    }
```

3. Write below code in viewDidLoad

   ```
    discoveryManager = [WeMoDiscoveryManager sharedWeMoDiscoveryManager];
   discoveryManager.deviceDiscoveryDelegate = self;
   [discoveryManager discoverDevices:WeMoUpnpInterface];
   ```
4. write Wemodiscovermanager delegate methods

   ```
   -(void)discoveryManager:(WeMoDiscoveryManager*)manager didFoundDevice:(WeMoControlDevice*)device
   }


   -(void)discoveryManager:(WeMoDiscoveryManager*)manager removeDeviceWithUdn:(NSString*)udn {
   }


   -(void)discoveryManagerRemovedAllDevices:(WeMoDiscoveryManager*)manager
   }
   ```

and keep break point on didFoundDevice

**Note** : before implementing this please check

a.weather devices configured or not

b.your wemo devices and your mobile should be in same network (wemo devices doesn't have remote access)

Comment: Hi Ravi, Since i have not yet started building my own app, i am using WEMO demo app.. and all these are already in place. But it doesn't detect my WeMo Link. I went through the Device data plist and notices no entry for WeMo Link or LED Bulbs, but entries for other WEMO Products, could this be the reason.?

Comment: Even i faced the same problem ,
entries for other WEMO Products is not the problem
WEMO SDK is not compatible for Wemo Link